# convert JSON buffer to string in perl

Tags: node.js, json, perl

**Issue**: Trying to write json buffer data to a file using Perl script.

**Scenario:**

I will have binary data in Postgres.

So to recreate the scenario, I converted "geeks" into binary format and stored in Postgres.

```
Input :  geeks
Output : 1100111 1100101 1100101 1101011 1110011
```

Nodejs query the binary data from the postgres and send the response as below in json format.

```
[
 {
   "lo_get": {
     "type": "Buffer",
     "data": [
       49,
       49,
       48,
       48,
       49,
       49,
       49,
       32,
       49,
       49,
       48,
       48,
       49,
       48,
       49,
       32,
       49,
       49,
       48,
       48,
       49,
       48,
       49,
       32,
       49,
       49,
       48,
       49,
       48,
       49,
       49,
       32,
       49,
       49,
       49,
       48,
       48,
       49,
       49
     ]
   }
 }
]
```

Below is the Perl script I have written  but I am not sure how to write the original string i.e. "geeks" to the file ..

```
    $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url);
    $res = $ua->request($req);
    $response = decode_json($res->content);
    if ($res->is_success & @$response) {
        $string = @$response[0]->{Output}->{data};
        print ($string);   
    } 

    open my $fh, ">", "data_out.json";
    print $fh encode_json($string);
    close $fh;
```

Am not sure how can i get the file with 'geeks' as content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```perl
my $binary =
   pack 'C*',
      @{ $response->[0]{lo_get}{data} };

say $binary;   # '1100111 1100101 1100101 1101011 1110011

my $bytes =
   pack 'C*',
      map { oct("0b$_") }
         split(' ', $binary);

say $bytes;    # geeks
```

---

> *It is converted into binary*

This makes no sense. In addition to the needless extra work converting the bytes into their binary representation or back when accessing the database, it multiplies the storage needed by 9 for nothing!

Comment: Thank you. I will have data in Postgres in binary format.
I created the above example to fit into my scenario.

Comment: But you're not storing it in a "binary format" (which means an efficient but probably not-human readable format); you're taking the "binary data" (which just means arbitrary bytes) and storing a *text* (i.e. human readable) representation of it. That's the opposite of what you claim to do!

Comment: That's right.  its binary data. Do I need to consider something else in this case?

Comment: Again, it's not binary data; it's text data. You should be storing binary data, not a text representation of it. You're confusing binary (a text representation of a number) with binary data (an extremly loose term which means something like "not-human readable because it uses all values of bytes").

Comment: okay. I got it.
In the case, of binary data. I may have to encode it in node js side and then decode it perl.
Can you please suggest me how can i handle it.
If you want , i can try to get some binary data and create another question.

Comment: Just remove the conversion of the string to its binary representation. On the Perl side, you'd simply use `my $bytes = pack 'C*', @{ $response->[0]{lo_get}{data} };`

Comment: great !! Thank you  !!

Comment: @ikegami -- definetly OP doesn't understand what he is doing, keep text in DB and convert it in ASCII representation of binary numbers -- hmm, why would somebody go this route? It sounds like insanity.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm to solution of the problem:

- Obtain data into hash ref
- use operator `map` with `split` to convert numbers into bin representation
- join array of converted with `chr` and `oct` bin numbers into a string
- process string as you desire

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

my $fname   = 'data.txt';
my $input   = do { local $/; <DATA> };
my $data    = from_json($input);

say 'Read: ' . Dumper($data);

my $str = join '', map { chr } @{$data->[0]{lo_get}{data}};
my @bin =  map { '0b' . $_ } split ' ', $str;

$str = join '', map { chr oct($_) } @bin;

say  'Out: ' . $str;

open my $fh, '>', $fname
    or die "Couldn't open $fname";

say $fh $str;

close $fh;

__DATA__
[
 {
   "lo_get": {
     "type": "Buffer",
     "data": [
       49,
       49,
       48,
       48,
       49,
       49,
       49,
       32,
       49,
       49,
       48,
       48,
       49,
       48,
       49,
       32,
       49,
       49,
       48,
       48,
       49,
       48,
       49,
       32,
       49,
       49,
       48,
       49,
       48,
       49,
       49,
       32,
       49,
       49,
       49,
       48,
       48,
       49,
       49
     ]
   }
 }
]
```

Run as `script.pl`

```
Read: $VAR1 = [
          {
            'lo_get' => {
                          'type' => 'Buffer',
                          'data' => [
                                      49,
                                      49,
                                      48,
                                      48,
                                      49,
                                      49,
                                      49,
                                      32,
                                      49,
                                      49,
                                      48,
                                      48,
                                      49,
                                      48,
                                      49,
                                      32,
                                      49,
                                      49,
                                      48,
                                      48,
                                      49,
                                      48,
                                      49,
                                      32,
                                      49,
                                      49,
                                      48,
                                      49,
                                      48,
                                      49,
                                      49,
                                      32,
                                      49,
                                      49,
                                      49,
                                      48,
                                      48,
                                      49,
                                      49
                                    ]
                        }
          }
        ];

Out: geeks
```

Content of the file `data.txt`

```
geeks
```

Comment: @ikegami -- wel OP has changed his question a few times, originally he had text, then he changed **array** to include ASCII representation of binary data, I had to change my code to adopt this change. Well I could not predict what is content of the binary data and to stay on safe side I assumed that it might be encoded in UTF-8 -- well, not bit problem to remove `:encoding(utf8)` on output.

Comment: Groups of 8 `1` and `0` chars, once decoded, chars between 0 and 255. The odds of it being something that be encoded using UTF-8 is highly unlikely.